# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{i}\binom{-1/2}{n-i} = 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove the following identity.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^n\binom{-1/2}{i}\binom{-1/2}{n-i} = 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By generalized binomial theorem we have $(1+x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-1/2}nx^n$ and this series converges absolutely for $|x|<1$, therefore $\bigl[(1+x)^{-1/2}\bigr]^2$ is the Cauchy product of the series with itself, hence

$$(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\,\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{-1/2}i\binom{-1/2}{n-i}\Biggr]\ x^n\,,$$

from which the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Vandermonde's convolution formula
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n(−1)^n\binom{−1/2}{i}\binom{−1/2}{n-i}&=(−1)^n\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{−1/2}{i}\binom{−1/2}{n-i}\\
&=(−1)^n\binom{-1}{n}\\
&=(−1)^n(−1)^n\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$